# 22.04 Dock making me crazy! Launched custom application shows twice in Dock, sort of

Tags: icons, dock

I have a .desktop launcher for a custom program in /usr/share/applications.

It appears under the "Activities" (top bar of 22.04's Desktop) when I search for it, and I right-clicked and added it to my Favorites. Now it has appeared on the Dock. This is the desired behavior. It displays with my chosen icon, and my chosen name when I hover the mouse cursor over it. So far, so good.

But when I launch it a new icon appears on the doc, the generic "gear" or "cog" icon, and the mouse-hover tooltip shows "Unknown." This icon has the little dot under it, indicating that it is a running program. The launcher with the desired icon and desired tooltip does not show that it is running.

How can I make it so the launched program does not create the second, generic "unknown" icon on the Dock, but instead just show the little dot under the icon I used to launch it?

Here is the contents of the .desktop launcher:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=StereoTool_FM
Comment=StereoTool audio processor for Air Chain
Exec=/home/kpov-staff/Desktop/StereoTool/StereoTool_FM/stereo_tool_gui_64_FM
Icon=/home/kpov-staff/Desktop/StereoTool/StereoTool_FM/stereo_tool_FM.svg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Audio
```

Adding the "shebang" at the top does not change the behavior. None of the default .desktop launchers that came with the OS have a shebang.

Thank you!

[ Edit: I played around with a launcher for another program showing the same undesired behavior and found that if I used (from command line) "xprop" and clicked on the program's open window I was able to view its WM_CLASS(STRING) = , then edited the .desktop for that program and added a new line StartupWMClass=, and now when that launcher is used I don't get the second "unknown" (gear icon) launcher. However, this doesn't help with the program I was inquiring about here, because the dev didn't assign a WM_CLASS to it. So I guess I have to go about figuring out how to assign that to it using xprop when it launches.]

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have help for what you are looking for, but wanted to leave a comment here that your question and recent edit just helped me a lot! I had the same frustration you had and followed your xprop/StartupWMClass advice and it did exactly what I needed. Thank you!